# "Failed to load" while installing Jfrog Container Registry from GCP marketplace

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-apps-marketplace, jfrog-container-registry

I am trying to install `JFrog Container Registry` from GCP marketplace (https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/JFrog+Partner+Integrations#JFrogPartnerIntegrations-gcpgke) . I have selected a project with a running GKE cluster. Clicking on `Configure` says `Failed to Load` with no more information. I do have `roles/owner` permissions on the project.

(I tried clicking thru another GCP Marketplace app - and it was able to locate the GKE cluster in the project and prompted for installing.)

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug with the listing. We (the JFrog team) are on it but if you want something up and running now, you can use the official HELM chart:

https://github.com/jfrog/charts/tree/master/stable/artifactory-jcr

Comment: Sounds good, i'll poll this thread - appreciate if you can post an update when it is fixed. Thanks!